# Calculating phi(k) for 1<k<N

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, primes

Given a large N, I need to iterate through all phi(k) such that 1 < k < N :

- time-complexity must be `O(N logN)`
- memory-complexity must be sub `O(N)` (since the values of N will be around 10<sup>12</sup>)

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Is that a Project Euler?

Comment: See "How many numbers below N are coprimes to N?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019040/how-many-numbers-below-n-are-coprimes-to-n about the same question -- how to calculate phi(k) quickly.

Comment: It's not a Project Euler, but it was sparked by one of their problems which I have now solved.

Comment: ShreevatsaR: That question was about calculating Phi(k) in isolation.  This question is about calculating all Phi(k) in sequence up to some N.  It's a related but still significantly different question.

Comment: Randomly: is order of iteration important?

Comment: Never mind; I could only get the memory complexity down to O(x/ln(x)) or so...

Comment: Order is not important; "quickly" is a member of O(n log n).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be done with Memory complexity O(Sqrt(N)) and CPU complexity O(N * Log(Log(N))) with an optimized windowed Sieve of Eratosthenes, as implemented in the code example below.

As no language was specified and as I do not know Python, I have implemented it in VB.net, however I can convert it to C# if you need that.

```vb
Imports System.Math

Public Class TotientSerialCalculator
    'Implements an extremely efficient Serial Totient(phi) calculator   '
    '  This implements an optimized windowed Sieve of Eratosthenes.  The'
    ' window size is set at Sqrt(N) both to optimize collecting and     '
    ' applying all of the Primes below Sqrt(N), and to minimize         '
    ' window-turning overhead.                                          '
    '                                                                   '
    ' CPU complexity is O( N * Log(Log(N)) ), which is virtually linear.'
    '                                                                   '
    ' MEM Complexity is O( Sqrt(N) ).                                   '
    '                                                                   '
    ' This is probalby the ideal combination, as any attempt to further '
    'reduce memory will almost certainly result in disproportionate increases'
    'in CPU complexity, and vice-versa.                                 '

    Structure NumberFactors
        Dim UnFactored As Long  'the part of the number that still needs to be factored'
        Dim Phi As Long 'the totient value progressively calculated'
        '               (equals total numbers less than N that are CoPrime to N)'
        'MEM = 8 bytes each'
    End Structure

    Private ReportInterval As Long
    Private PrevLast As Long     'the last value in the previous window'
    Private FirstValue As Long   'the first value in this windows range'
    Private WindowSize As Long
    Private LastValue As Long    'the last value in this windows range'
    Private NextFirst As Long    'the first value in the next window'

    'Array that stores all of the NumberFactors in the current window.'
    ' this is the primary memory consumption for the class and it'
    ' is 16 * Sqrt(N) Bytes, which is O(Sqrt(N)).'
    Public Numbers() As NumberFactors
    ' For N=10^12 (1 trilion), this will be 16MB, which should be bearable anywhere.'
    '(note that the Primes() array is a secondary memory consumer'
    '  at O(pi(Sqrt(N)), which will be within 10x of O(Sqrt(N)))'

    Public Event EmitTotientPair(ByVal k As Long, ByVal Phi As Long)

    '===== The Routine To Call: ========================'
    Public Sub EmitTotientPairsToN(ByVal N As Long)
        'Routine to Emit Totient pairs {k, Phi(k)} for k = 1 to N'
        '   2009-07-14, RBarryYoung, Created.'
        Dim i As Long
        Dim k As Long   'the current number being factored'
        Dim p As Long   'the current prime factor'

        'Establish the Window frame:'
        '   note: WindowSize is the critical value that controls both memory'
        '    usage and CPU consumption and must be SQRT(N) for it to work optimally.'
        WindowSize = Ceiling(Sqrt(CDbl(N)))
        ReDim Numbers(0 To WindowSize - 1)

        'Initialize the first window:'
        MapWindow(1)
        Dim IsFirstWindow As Boolean = True

        'adjust this to control how often results are show'
        ReportInterval = N / 100

        'Allocate the primes array to hold the primes list:'
        '  Only primes <= SQRT(N) are needed for factoring'
        '  PiMax(X) is a Max estimate of the number of primes <= X'
        Dim Primes() As Long, PrimeIndex As Long, NextPrime As Long
        'init the primes list and its pointers'
        ReDim Primes(0 To PiMax(WindowSize) - 1)
        Primes(0) = 2   '"prime" the primes list with the first prime'
        NextPrime = 1

        'Map (and Remap) the window with Sqrt(N) numbers, Sqrt(N) times to'
        ' sequentially map all of the numbers <= N.'
        Do
            'Sieve the primes across the current window'
            PrimeIndex = 0
            'note: cant use enumerator for the loop below because NextPrime'
            ' changes during the first window as new primes <= SQRT(N) are accumulated'
            Do While PrimeIndex < NextPrime
                'get the next prime in the list'
                p = Primes(PrimeIndex)
                'find the first multiple of (p) in the current window range'
                k = PrevLast + p - (PrevLast Mod p)

                Do
                    With Numbers(k - FirstValue)
                        .UnFactored = .UnFactored \ p   'always works the first time'
                        .Phi = .Phi * (p - 1)           'Phi = PRODUCT( (Pi-1)*Pi^(Ei-1) )'
                        'The loop test that follows is probably the central CPU overhead'
                        ' I believe that it is O(N*Log(Log(N)), which is virtually O(N)'
                        ' ( for instance at N = 10^12, Log(Log(N)) = 3.3 )'
                        Do While (.UnFactored Mod p) = 0
                            .UnFactored = .UnFactored \ p
                            .Phi = .Phi * p
                        Loop
                    End With

                    'skip ahead to the next multiple of p: '
                    '(this is what makes it so fast, never have to try prime factors that dont apply)'
                    k += p
                    'repeat until we step out of the current window:'
                Loop While k < NextFirst

                'if this is the first window, then scan ahead for primes'
                If IsFirstWindow Then
                    For i = Primes(NextPrime - 1) + 1 To p ^ 2 - 1  'the range of possible new primes'
                        'Dont go beyond the first window'
                        If i >= WindowSize Then Exit For
                        If Numbers(i - FirstValue).UnFactored = i Then
                            'this is a prime less than SQRT(N), so add it to the list.'
                            Primes(NextPrime) = i
                            NextPrime += 1
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                PrimeIndex += 1     'move to the next prime'
            Loop

            'Now Finish & Emit each one'
            For k = FirstValue To LastValue
                With Numbers(k - FirstValue)
                    'Primes larger than Sqrt(N) will not be finished: '
                    If .UnFactored > 1 Then
                        'Not done factoring, must be an large prime factor remaining: '
                        .Phi = .Phi * (.UnFactored - 1)
                        .UnFactored = 1
                    End If

                    'Emit the value pair: (k, Phi(k)) '
                    EmitPhi(k, .Phi)
                End With
            Next

            're-Map to the next window '
            IsFirstWindow = False
            MapWindow(NextFirst)
        Loop While FirstValue <= N
    End Sub

    Sub EmitPhi(ByVal k As Long, ByVal Phi As Long)
        'just a placeholder for now, that raises an event to the display form' 
        ' periodically for reporting purposes.  Change this to do the actual'
        ' emitting.'
        If (k Mod ReportInterval) = 0 Then
            RaiseEvent EmitTotientPair(k, Phi)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub MapWindow(ByVal FirstVal As Long)
        'Efficiently reset the window so that we do not have to re-allocate it.'

        'init all of the boundary values'
        FirstValue = FirstVal
        PrevLast = FirstValue - 1
        NextFirst = FirstValue + WindowSize
        LastValue = NextFirst - 1

        'Initialize the Numbers prime factor arrays'
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To WindowSize - 1
            With Numbers(i)
                .UnFactored = i + FirstValue 'initially equal to the number itself'
                .Phi = 1        'starts at mulplicative identity(1)'
            End With
        Next
    End Sub

    Function PiMax(ByVal x As Long) As Long
        'estimate of pi(n) == {primes <= (n)} that is never less'
        ' than the actual number of primes. (from P. Dusart, 1999)'
        Return (x / Log(x)) * (1.0 + 1.2762 / Log(x))
    End Function
End Class
```

Note that at O(N * Log(Log(N))), this routine is factoring each number at O(Log(Log(N))) on average which is much, much faster than the fastest single N factorization algorithms sited by some of the replies here.  In fact, at N = 10^12 it is ***2400*** times faster!

I have tested this routine on my 2Ghz Intel Core 2 laptop and it computes over 3,000,000 Phi() values per second.  At this speed, it would take you about 4 days to compute 10^12 values.  I have also tested it for correctness up to 100,000,000 without any errors.  It is based in 64-bit integers, so anything up to 2^63 (10^19) should be accurate (though too slow for anyone).

I also have a Visual Studio WinForm (also VB.net) for running/testing it, that I can provide if you want it.

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

As requested in the comments, I have added below a C# version of the code.  However, because I am currently in the middle of some other projects, I do not have time to convert it myself, so I have used one of the online VB to C# conversion sites (http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/). So be aware that this was auto-converted and I have not had time to test or check it myself yet.

```cs
using System.Math;
public class TotientSerialCalculator {

    // Implements an extremely efficient Serial Totient(phi) calculator   '
    //   This implements an optimized windowed Sieve of Eratosthenes.  The'
    //  window size is set at Sqrt(N) both to optimize collecting and     '
    //  applying all of the Primes below Sqrt(N), and to minimize         '
    //  window-turning overhead.                                          '
    //                                                                    '
    //  CPU complexity is O( N * Log(Log(N)) ), which is virtually linear.'
    //                                                                    '
    //  MEM Complexity is O( Sqrt(N) ).                                   '
    //                                                                    '
    //  This is probalby the ideal combination, as any attempt to further '
    // reduce memory will almost certainly result in disproportionate increases'
    // in CPU complexity, and vice-versa.                                 '
    struct NumberFactors {

        private long UnFactored;  // the part of the number that still needs to be factored'
        private long Phi;
    }

    private long ReportInterval;
    private long PrevLast;       // the last value in the previous window'
    private long FirstValue;     // the first value in this windows range'
    private long WindowSize;
    private long LastValue;      // the last value in this windows range'
    private long NextFirst;      // the first value in the next window'

    // Array that stores all of the NumberFactors in the current window.'
    //  this is the primary memory consumption for the class and it'
    //  is 16 * Sqrt(N) Bytes, which is O(Sqrt(N)).'
    public NumberFactors[] Numbers;
    //  For N=10^12 (1 trilion), this will be 16MB, which should be bearable anywhere.'
    // (note that the Primes() array is a secondary memory consumer'
    //   at O(pi(Sqrt(N)), which will be within 10x of O(Sqrt(N)))'

//NOTE: this part looks like it did not convert correctly
    public event EventHandler EmitTotientPair;
    private long k;
    private long Phi;

    // ===== The Routine To Call: ========================'
    public void EmitTotientPairsToN(long N) {
        // Routine to Emit Totient pairs {k, Phi(k)} for k = 1 to N'
        //    2009-07-14, RBarryYoung, Created.'
        long i;
        long k;
        // the current number being factored'
        long p;
        // the current prime factor'
        // Establish the Window frame:'
        //    note: WindowSize is the critical value that controls both memory'
        //     usage and CPU consumption and must be SQRT(N) for it to work optimally.'
        WindowSize = Ceiling(Sqrt(double.Parse(N)));
        object Numbers;
        this.MapWindow(1);
        bool IsFirstWindow = true;
        ReportInterval = (N / 100);
        // Allocate the primes array to hold the primes list:'
        //   Only primes <= SQRT(N) are needed for factoring'
        //   PiMax(X) is a Max estimate of the number of primes <= X'
        long[] Primes;
        long PrimeIndex;
        long NextPrime;
        // init the primes list and its pointers'
        object Primes;
        -1;
        Primes[0] = 2;
        // "prime" the primes list with the first prime'
        NextPrime = 1;
        // Map (and Remap) the window with Sqrt(N) numbers, Sqrt(N) times to'
        //  sequentially map all of the numbers <= N.'
        for (
        ; (FirstValue <= N); 
        ) {
            PrimeIndex = 0;
            // note: cant use enumerator for the loop below because NextPrime'
            //  changes during the first window as new primes <= SQRT(N) are accumulated'
            while ((PrimeIndex < NextPrime)) {
                // get the next prime in the list'
                p = Primes[PrimeIndex];
                // find the first multiple of (p) in the current window range'
                k = (PrevLast 
                            + (p 
                            - (PrevLast % p)));
                for (
                ; (k < NextFirst); 
                ) {
                    // With...
                    UnFactored;
                    p;
                    // always works the first time'
                    (Phi 
                                * (p - 1));
                    while (// TODO: Warning!!!! NULL EXPRESSION DETECTED...
                    ) {
                        (UnFactored % p);
                        UnFactored;
                        (Phi * p);
                    }

                    // skip ahead to the next multiple of p: '
                    // (this is what makes it so fast, never have to try prime factors that dont apply)'
                    k = (k + p);
                    // repeat until we step out of the current window:'
                }

                // if this is the first window, then scan ahead for primes'
                if (IsFirstWindow) {
                    for (i = (Primes[(NextPrime - 1)] + 1); (i 
                                <= (p | (2 - 1))); i++) {
                        // the range of possible new primes'
                        // TODO: Warning!!! The operator should be an XOR ^ instead of an OR, but not available in CodeDOM
                        // Dont go beyond the first window'
                        if ((i >= WindowSize)) {
                            break;
                        }

                        if ((Numbers[(i - FirstValue)].UnFactored == i)) {
                            // this is a prime less than SQRT(N), so add it to the list.'
                            Primes[NextPrime] = i;
                            NextPrime++;
                        }

                    }

                }

                PrimeIndex++;
                // move to the next prime'
            }

            // Now Finish & Emit each one'
            for (k = FirstValue; (k <= LastValue); k++) {
                // With...
                // Primes larger than Sqrt(N) will not be finished: '
                if ((Numbers[(k - FirstValue)].UnFactored > 1)) {
                    // Not done factoring, must be an large prime factor remaining: '
                    (Numbers[(k - FirstValue)].Phi * (Numbers[(k - FirstValue)].UnFactored - 1).UnFactored) = 1;
                    Numbers[(k - FirstValue)].Phi = 1;
                }

                // Emit the value pair: (k, Phi(k)) '
                this.EmitPhi(k, Numbers[(k - FirstValue)].Phi);
            }

            // re-Map to the next window '
            IsFirstWindow = false;
            this.MapWindow(NextFirst);
        }

    }

    void EmitPhi(long k, long Phi) {
        // just a placeholder for now, that raises an event to the display form' 
        //  periodically for reporting purposes.  Change this to do the actual'
        //  emitting.'
        if (((k % ReportInterval) 
                    == 0)) {
            EmitTotientPair(k, Phi);
        }

    }

    public void MapWindow(long FirstVal) {
        // Efficiently reset the window so that we do not have to re-allocate it.'
        // init all of the boundary values'
        FirstValue = FirstVal;
        PrevLast = (FirstValue - 1);
        NextFirst = (FirstValue + WindowSize);
        LastValue = (NextFirst - 1);
        // Initialize the Numbers prime factor arrays'
        long i;
        for (i = 0; (i 
                    <= (WindowSize - 1)); i++) {
            // With...
            // initially equal to the number itself'
            Phi = 1;
            // starts at mulplicative identity(1)'
        }

    }

    long PiMax(long x) {
        // estimate of pi(n) == {primes <= (n)} that is never less'
        //  than the actual number of primes. (from P. Dusart, 1999)'
        return ((x / Log(x)) * (1 + (1.2762 / Log(x))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for very clear, readable code. Also thanks for some interesting benchmarks although I expect VB.net to be quite slow in comparison to optimized C; I expect runtime for 10^12 numbers could be reduced to a day or less.

Comment: Yes, I agree, with a highly optimized mid-level language like C, a 4x speedup to 1 Day seems reasonable.  The real challenge will be what to do with 10 Million Totient values a second that won't significantly slow it down.

Comment: Hello, I am doing a research project where I would like to implement the algorithm you have described above. However, I am unfamiliar with VB.net. Would it be possible for you to send me the pseudocode, or implement it in C? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @nicole I have updated my answer with an auto-generated conversion.  I do not have time to test it right now, but the Event declaration looks like it did not convert correctly.

Answer (score 5):

No one has found a faster way to calculate phi(k) (aka, [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)) than by first finding the prime factors of k.  The world's best mathematicians have thrown many CPU cycles at the problem since 1977, since finding a faster way to solve this problem would create a weakness in the [RSA public-key algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_algorithm).  (Both the public and the private key in RSA are calculated based on phi(n), where n is the product of two large primes.)

Comment: What you say is true, but only for single values of (k).  There is no reason that I know of to believe that O(Compute(phi(k)))|0<k<=N == N*O(Compute(phi(k))).  Indeed, it seems at first glance that something as simple as an optimized windowed Sieve of Eratosthenes demonstrates otherwise.

Comment: No one is arguing that O(Compute(phi(k))) | 0 < k <= N == N * O(Compute(phi(k))).  The problem is still to find the prime factors of extremely large k.

Comment: Well 10^12 (or 2^40) would be considered moderate in this field, not large or extremely large.  And the problem isn't really to find the prime factors of k, but to find the prime factors of all k<=N, which can be done thousands of times faster than the routines used to factor things like the RSA public keys.

Comment: Right.  I meant to say "an extremely large number of k," which is much different.

Answer (score 4):

The computation of phi(k) has to be done using the prime factorization of k, which is the only sensible way of doing it. If you need a refresher on that, [wikipedia carries the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Computing_Euler.27s_function).

If you now have to compute all prime divisors of every number between 1 and a large N, you'll die of old age before seeing any result, so I'd go the other way around, i.e. build all numbers below N, using their possible prime factors, i.e. all primes less than or equal to N.

Your problem is therefore going to be similar to computing all divisors of a number, only you do not know what is the maximum number of times you may find a certain prime in the factorization beforehand. Tweaking an iterator originally written by Tim Peters on the python list (something [I've blogged about](http://numericalrecipes.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/divisors/)...) to include the totient function, a possible implementation in python that yields k, phi(k) pairs could be as follows:

```
def composites(factors, N) :
    """
    Generates all number-totient pairs below N, unordered, from the prime factors.
    """
    ps = sorted(set(factors))
    omega = len(ps)

    def rec_gen(n = 0) :
        if n == omega :
            yield (1,1)
        else :
            pows = [(1,1)]
            val = ps[n]
            while val <= N :
                pows += [(val, val - pows[-1][0])]
                val *= ps[n]
            for q, phi_q in rec_gen(n + 1) :
                for p, phi_p in pows :
                    if p * q > N :
                        break
                    else :
                        yield p * q, phi_p * phi_q

    for p in rec_gen() :
        yield p
```

If you need help on computing all prime factors below N, I've also [blogged about it](http://numericalrecipes.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/prime-numbers-2-the-sieve-of-erathostenes/)... Keep in mind, though that computing all primes below 10<sup>12</sup> is in itself quite a remarkable feat...

Comment: re [your blog post](https://numericalrecipes.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/divisors/) about "Ordered Generation of Divisors", have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992904/enumerate-factors-of-a-number-directly-in-ascending-order-without-sorting/30181351#30181351)?

Comment: That's a lot to digest, but it looks (very) interesting. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Is this from Project Euler 245? I remember that question, and I have given up on it.

The fastest way I found for calculating totient was to multiply the prime factors (p-1) together, given that k has no repeated factors (which was never the case if I remember the problem correctly).

So for calculating factors, it would probably be best to use [gmpy.next_prime](http://gmpy.sourceforge.net/) or [pyecm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyecm) (elliptic curve factorization).

You could also sieve the prime factors as Jaime suggests. For numbers up to 10<sup>12</sup>, the maximum prime factor is below 1 million which should be reasonable.

If you memoize factorizations, it could speed up your phi function even more.

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of problems I'm using an iterator that returns for each integer *m < N* the list of primes < sqrt(*N*) that divide m. To implement such an iterator I'm using an array *A* of length *R* where *R* > sqrt(*N*). At each point the array *A* contains list of primes that divide integers *m .. m+R*-1. I.e. *A*[*m* % *R*] contains primes dividing *m*. Each prime *p* is in exactly one list, i.e. in *A*[*m* % *R*] for the smallest integer in the range *m* .. *m*+*R*-1 that is divisible by *p*. When generating the next element of the iterator simply the list in *A*[*m* % *R*] is returned. Then the list of primes are removed from *A*[*m* % *R*] and each prime p is appended to *A*[(*m*+*p*) % R].

With a list of primes < sqrt(*N*) dividing *m* it is easy to find the factorization of *m*, since there is at most one prime larger than sqrt(*N*).

This method has complexity O(*N* log(log(*N*))) under the assumption that all operations including list operations take O(1). The memory requirement is O(sqrt(*N*)).

There is unfortunately, some constant overhead here, hence I was looking for a more elegant way to generate the values phi(n), but so for I've not been successful.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'm struggling to work out the values in array A. What would A be in the case that N=20 and R=5. Cheers!

Comment: Very cool approach.  But don't you need the list of primes sorted (or at least grouped) in order to calculate Phi(m) from it?  How do you keep them sorted or do you have to sort them for each m?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't answer earlier. I don't have to sort the list of primes. All that is necessary is that when the iterator returns the list of prime factors < sqrt(N) for m that A[m % R] contains these prime factors. To get phi it is still necessary to factor m, but given that we have all the prime factors this is easy. I did recently implement this method: the computation of all phi(n) for n < 10^12 takes 17h on a Core 2. I'm probably doing a little more operations than the sieve method, but my method seems more cache friendly since I'm using less then 5MB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an efficient python generator. The caveat is that it doesn't yield the results in order.  It is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110008/412529 .

Memory complexity is O(log(N)) as it only has to store a list of prime factors for a single number at a time.

CPU complexity is just barely superlinear, something like O(N log log N).

```
def totientsbelow(N):
    allprimes = primesbelow(N+1)
    def rec(n, partialtot=1, min_p = 0):
        for p in allprimes:
            if p > n:
                break
            # avoid double solutions such as (6, [2,3]), and (6, [3,2])
            if p < min_p: continue
            yield (p, p-1, [p])
            for t, tot2, r in rec(n//p, partialtot, min_p = p): # uses integer division
                yield (t*p, tot2 * p if p == r[0] else tot2 * (p-1), [p] + r)

    for n, t, factors in rec(N):
        yield (n, t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go the other way around.  Instead of factorizing an integer k to get phi(k), you can attempt to generate all integers from 1 to N from primes and get phi(k) quickly.  For example, if P<sub>n</sub> is the maximum prime that is less than N, you can generate all integers less than N by

P<sub>1</sub> <sup>i <sub>1</sub></sup> * P<sub>2</sub> <sup>i <sub>2</sub></sup> * ... * P<sub>n</sub> <sup>i <sub>n</sub></sup> where each i<sub>j</sub> run from 0 to [log (N) / log (P<sub>j</sub>)] ([] is the floor function).

That way, you can get phi(k) quickly wihout expensive prime factorization and still iterate through all k between 1 and N (not in order but I think you don't care about order).

Comment: About memory, by prime number theorem, n ~ N/ln(N). So, a good implmentation should have O(n/log n) memory usage.

See prime number theorem here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Sieve the totients to *n*:

```
(define (totients n)
  (let ((tots (make-vector (+ n 1))))
    (do ((i 0 (+ i 1))) ((< n i))
      (vector-set! tots i i))
    (do ((i 2 (+ i 1))) ((< n i) tots)
      (when (= i (vector-ref tots i))
        (vector-set! tots i (- i 1))
        (do ((j (+ i i) (+ i j))) ((< n j))
          (vector-set! tots j
            (* (vector-ref tots j) (- 1 (/ i)))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This factorizes N = PQ, where P & Q are prime.

Works quite well, in Elixir or Erlang.

You can try different generators for your pseudo-random sequence. `x*x + 1` is commonly used.

This line: `defp f0(x, n), do: rem((x * x) + 1, n)`

Other possible points of improvement: better or alternative *gcd*, *rem* and *abs* functions

```
defmodule Factorizer do

  def factorize(n) do
    t = System.system_time

    x = pollard(n, 2_000_000, 2_000_000)
    y = div(n, x)
    p = min(x, y)
    q = max(x, y)

    t = System.system_time - t

    IO.puts "
Factorized #{n}: into [#{p} , #{q}] in #{t} μs
"

    {p, q}
  end

  defp gcd(a,0), do: a
  defp gcd(a,b), do: gcd(b,rem(a,b))

  defp pollard(n, a, b) do
    a = f0(a, n)
    b = f0(f0(b, n), n)

    p = gcd(abs(b - a), n)

    case p > 1 do
      true  -> p
      false -> pollard(n, a, b)
    end
  end

  defp f0(x, n), do: rem((x * x) + 1, n)

end
```