# What is the best way to find a prime number?

Tags: c++

what will be the best way to find a prime number so that the time complexity is much reduced.

Comment: Are you looking for prime numbers, or are you looking to test if a number you have is prime?

Comment: "2".  Now you're done for all time.

Comment: Unless, you had some, you know, "requirements" or "specifications".

Comment: finding prime numbers between range of numbers..
say between 1 and 99999..

Comment: there are approximately 1000 duplicates of your question along with an answer at SO, and millions more to find via google

Comment: Do you want to be absolutely sure they're prime, or will you be happy if they're just almost certainly prime?  (For large numbers, the latter is far faster.)  Do you want to find all primes in a given range, or just some of them?  What ranges did you have in mind?  What's about the highest number (order of magnitude would be fine) you'd be interested in?

Comment: Build a list of primes first. Then you can use this list for future references.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When it comes to finding prime numbers, the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and the [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) are two possible solutions. The Sieve of Eratosthenes has a complexity of O((n log n)(log log n)). The Sieve of Atkin has a complexity of O(N / log log n).

If you have a number and you want to find out if it's prime, that is called performing a [primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). The naive approach is to check all numbers m from 2 to sqrt(n) and verify that n % m is not 0. If you want to expand this slightly, you can throw out all even numbers (except 2). There are also some other enhancements to this naive approach that might improve performance, along with other, more advanced techniques.

Comment: +1, I've never heard of sieve of Atkins before. Thanks.

Comment: Throw out the even number apart from 2...

Comment: Jonathan - Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: @ThomasOwens What is reason for checking from 2 to sqrt(n) in the naive approach ?

Comment: @Geek If the number was not prime, at least one factor must be below sqrt(n). Assuming you're not trying to factor the number, it doesn't matter what all of the factors are. You just need to know that some factor exists.

Comment: The usually implemented basic versions of the algorithms are at asymptotic computation complexities of O(n log log n) and O(n) for the Sieve of Eratosthenes and the Sieve of Atkin, respectively.  The SoE figure used in this answer doesn't apply to the same algorithm but rather to some sort of incremental algorithm using perhaps a Priority Queue.  The SoA figure is often quoted for an esoteric theoretical modification of the basic SoA algorithm that I don't believe has ever been implemented, even by its authors (Their reference primegen SoA implementation has a theoretical O(n) performance).

Answer (score 17):

Use [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is if you want to enumerate primes. If you want to generate a large prime, generate a random odd number and [check for primality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Comment: Wikipedia points to the Sieve of Atkin as being more efficient than the Sieve of Eratosthenes...

Comment: Thomas, I've removed the claim of optimality. Thanks.

Comment: +1. The Sieve of Eratosthenes is supposed to be fairly easy to implement, although I've never done so...perhaps I will, just to see. It might not be the best performer, but from what I can tell, it's usually good enough.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, the WP article indicates that the Sieve of Atkin is more efficient based on asymptotic computation complexity of O(n log log n) for the Sieve of Eratosthenes and O(n) for the SoA.  In fact, the new edited articles show that although the basic SoA uses a constant about 0.258717... times the range operations, for many ranges up to extremely high practical limits, a maximally wheel factorized SoE actually has less operations and the operations are simpler.  Thus, a maximally wheel factorized and optimized SoE for equivalent complexity as the SoA is likely never slower than SoA.

Answer (score 13):

If it's below a certain range, best way would be to look it up in a precomputed list. There's plenty of them, up to very high numbers.

Example, all the primes up to 10,000,000,000 at http://www.prime-numbers.org/

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/221/):

```
int findPrimeNumber() {
    return 2; // guaranteed to be prime
}
```

Comment: If you're going to post a purely humorous answer to a serious question, at least make it community wiki.

Comment: I would come back with the smart-alecky response that this IS a serious answer... but really I just didn't know you could make answers community wiki (and that I honestly did not expect any upvotes for such a ridiculous answer).

Comment: ahh crap you beat me to it. lol

Comment: To be honest, it does satisfy the OP's request.  However, my finely honed sense of telepathy, gained by trying to get requirements out of users without violating the Hague and Geneva Conventions, suggests that this isn't all the OP wants.

Comment: huh, would you look at that, you can make answers CW now!  How long have I been blind to that feature?

Comment: But can you post this in Objective C?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate primes from 1 to whatever, then the fastest way is probably a wheeled Sieve as implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024640/calculating-phik-for-1kn/1134851#1134851), which can typically test more than 3,000,000 candidate primes a second on an average laptop (and that's using an *unoptimized* language like VB.net), and factor the non-primes to boot.  In c++ it could be easily 5 to 20 times faster.

Comment: Although I'm not a fan of VB.NET, the "5-20" times faster seems a little over the top. But... +1 for the link

Comment: Granted it's hard to say: but my understanding is that VB.net does no loop, etc. code-type optimizations and this program/algorithm is *exactly* the kind of algorithm can go gangbusters on. OTOH, if it were making heavy use of non-replaceable .NET calls, then the difference would be a lot less.

Comment: (wish I was more proficient in VC++, I'd just re-code it and see what the difference was).

Comment: OTOH .NET uses jit which for a repetetive task like this should be able to optimize quite a bit.

Comment: Hmm, where could I find out more about jit optimizations?

Comment: RBarryYoung, see "Is Managed Code Slower Than Unmanaged Code?" http://www.grimes.demon.co.uk/dotnet/man_unman.htm

Answer (score 1):

Although there are more efficient algorithms, the [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) primality test is one of the simplest tests to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different questions:

1) How to find `if a number` is a prime number? If you discover an efficient algorithm for this one, you will be famous for the next `2000` years ;)

2) How to find `the prime numbers` up to a limit `N`?

probably this is what you are asking about. `Sieve of Atkin` is the most efficient one If your range or limit `N` is really big number. In reasonable ranges, you could implement an optimized variation of Sieve of Eratosthenes. I found these two sites to be more than useful:

- [`The Black Key Sieve`](http://www.qsl.net/w2gl/blackkey.html)
- [`The Sieve of Eratosthenes`](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/prime_sieve.html)

**EDIT: @avakar**

While I am more than beginner on the subject, I don't think `AKS` is the waited algorithm! From the same source:

> However, some composite numbers also
>   satisfy the equivalence. The proof of
>   correctness for AKS consists of
>   showing that there exists a suitably
>   small r and suitably small set of
>   integers A such that if the
>   equivalence holds for all such a in A
>   then n must be prime.

Comment: There is an efficient (as in polynomial) algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

Comment: -1: There already *are* extremely efficient algorithms for this.  Sub-linear, for serial tests.

Comment: What is described in the "Black Key Sieve" is just a primitive version of a wheeled sieve.

Comment: (took the -1 back, considering there is some explanation of the differences)

Comment: AraK, AKS will polynomially and deterministically determine whether an integer is a prime. The two sentences you cited merely point out what must be proven in order for the algorithm to be considered correct. (And the original paper provides the proof.)

Comment: The Sieve of Atkin is not the best algorithm for finding a sequence of primes for a very big range - there is no practical proof it is:  1) It can be shown as per the new WP Sieve of Eratosthenes article that a maximally wheel factorized SoE has less operations than the SoA for any practical range using a "one huge memory array" model, and 2) Atkin and Bernstein's reference "primegen" implementation of the SoA gets very slow for large ranges as compared to a maximally wheel factorized (and optimized) SoE primesieve due to inefficiencies in "prime squares free" as spans exceed buffer range..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at existing libraries e.g. OpenSSL and GNU MP.

Answer (score -2):

I found a way.But may its lengthy, but its perfect ..no flaws in it.

```
package javaapplication4;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{ 
    static Vector vprime = new Vector();
    static Vector vnotprime = new Vector();
    static Vector newVect = new Vector(new LinkedHashSet());
    static TreeSet<Integer> st = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    static int n = 0;
    static int starr[];    

    void prime()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number to begin");
        int beg = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number to end");
        int end = sc.nextInt();
        try
        {
            for (int i = beg; i <= end; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    vnotprime.add(i);
                    st.add(i);
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    vprime.add(i);
                }
                if (i%2 != 0 && i%(Math.sqrt(i)) != 0)
                {
                    vprime.add(i);
                }
                if (i%2 == 0 && i != 2)
                {
                    vnotprime.add(i);
                    st.add(i);
                }
                if (i%(Math.sqrt(i)) == 0)
                {
                    vnotprime.add(i);
                    st.add(i);   
                }
                /*if (i%(Math.sqrt(i)) == 0 && i != 1)
                {
                    vnotprime.add(i);
                }*/
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter proper value");
        }   
    }

    void showprime()
    {
        System.out.println("Prime Numbers are");
        Iterator it = vprime.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next());
            for (int i : st)
            {    
            }
        }
    }

    void shownonprime()
    {
        System.out.println("these are non-Prime Numbers are");
        Iterator it = st.iterator();
        int len = st.size(), k = 0;
        starr = new int[len];
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
        for (int i:st)
        {
            starr[k++] = i;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.prime();
        m.showprime();
        m.shownonprime();
        for(int i = 0; i < starr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("I got it " + starr[i]);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable, please format it better!