# Calculating the sum of phi(k) for 1 <= k <= N?

Tags: algorithm

I need to calculate the sum of phi(k) for 1 <= k <= N where N = 1,000,000 and phi(k) is Euler's totient function. This is for a project Euler problem. I've already solved it using this previous [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024640/calculating-phik-for-1kn) where it asks to calculate each value of phi(k) for 1 < k < N. However, I wonder if any further optimizations can be made since we only require the final sum of the phi(k) and not the individual value of each addend.

Comment: You should checkout the properties of the Euler totient at [Other formulae involving phi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae_involving_.CF.86). For example, the even/odd property looks like it can help re-use phi(k) to calculate phi(2*k).

Comment: I answered how to calculate this in O(n^(2/3)), and a more generic variant too, on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/579587/111135).

Answer (score 5):

The [Wikipedia page on Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae_involving_.CF.86) includes a formula due to Arnold Wafisz for the sum of φ(k) for k from 1 to n:

```
sum(1<=k<=n) φ(k) = (1 + sum(1<=k<=n) μ(k)*(floor(n/k))^2) / 2
```

(It's a lot easier to read on Wikipedia.)

The [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) μ(*k*) is 0 if *k* has any squared prime factor, and otherwise (-1)<sup>*f*</sup> where *f* is the number of unique prime factors in *k*. (In other words, it is 1 if *k*'s prime factorization has an even number of unique primes; -1 if it has an odd number; and 0 if some prime appears more than once.) You should be able to use a modified sieve to rapidly compute μ(*k*).

That might turn out to be a bit faster.

Comment: I think this formula is a very good way.  I believe you can evaluate this formula in sublinear time O(n^0.75) by using a method described in the solution pdf to Project Euler problem 73.