# A more optimised way to find if a set of numbers have a prime number in it

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, numbers, primes

What could be a better, more efficient way to find if a given set of numbers have at least one prime number in it? We can test each number one by one, but could there be a better, more optimized solution?

Comment: What is the range of the numbers?

Comment: @AakashM **No negatives**, so that essentially means a range of 0 to N. The goal is to find if there is even one prime number in the set or not.

Comment: So these are unconstrained `BigNumber`s of some kind? Or 32-bit integers? Or?

Comment: @AakashM Yes, 32-bit integers

Comment: There are too man primes in 32-bit for any clever fast prime-check. So I think in worst case you must check them all.

Comment: @MrSmith42 **Okay, say we have to do the same for numbers up to 10,000.** Can there be any way other than checking the primality of all the numbers until a prime is found?

Comment: @jadebit: Of cause you need to look at all numbers (in worst case). So you cannot get better than `O(n)`. The question is what do you need to do with them. If they are <=10000 you can simply look them up in a Set of all primes <=10000 (takes `O(1)`. => Total of `O(n)`.

Comment: It all depends on what the set looks like.  Random numbers?  Test them one by one.  A bunch of numbers out of a specific range of large numbers?  Run a prime sieve for that range.  etc

Comment: For number ranges like `all integers from 1 to N`, the fastest algorithms are called "Sieves".  Variations of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) are the most common, and there are many examples available (I have several [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134851/109122)).

Comment: There are deterministic versions of the Miller-Rabin test for 32-bit integers that are faster than doing trial division, especially for values near the upper bound. Also there are 6542 primes less than 2^16, so you can precompute these into a set to be used for checking the primality of values in your set < 2^16.

Comment: What’s your approach?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there are ~700MByte of 32bit primes `m= ~700M / 4` and if you do 32bit SoE its only 512MByte so if you have enough memory you can:

1. find `max` of your array `O(n)`
2. use SoE to get all primes up to `max`

   This might be pre-computed and stored in file, You can either store list of primes of SoE map. List of primes files are [downloadable online](http://www.umopit.ru/CompLab/primes32eng.htm) in binary form (fast to load)
3. check each number if it is present in primes

   this is `O(n*log(m))` if list of primes or `O(n)` if SoE map

If memory is a problem then:

1. sort your numbers ascending `~O(n.log(n))`
2. do incremental primes search `~O(m^2)?`

   where `m` is max of your array
3. for each found prime check if it is present in array (incrementaly) `~O(1)`

Also see this for some additional ideas:

- [Prime numbers by Eratosthenes quicker sequential than concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214)

You can also combine SoE with the division just like I did in the `int isprime(int p)` in previous link. I have 8 smaller periodic SoE maps `primes_map[]` for first primes to hugely speed up the division ignoring majority of non primes with single division (aligning to SoE map period).