# fastest calculation of largest prime factor of 512 bit number in python

Tags: python, primes, factorization

i am simulating my crypto scheme in python, i am a new user to it.

p = 512 bit number and i need to calculate largest prime factor for it, i am looking for two things:

1. Fastest code to process this large prime factorization
2. Code that can take 512 bit of number as input and can handle it.

I have seen different implementations in other languages, my whole code is in python and this is last point where i am stuck. So let me know if there is any implementation in python.

Kindly explain in simple as i am new user to python

sorry for bad english.

**edit (taken from OP's answer below):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def highest_prime_factor(n):
   if isprime(n):
      return n
   for x in xrange(2,n ** 0.5 + 1):
      if not n % x:
         return highest_prime_factor(n/x)

def isprime(n):
   for x in xrange(2,n ** 0.5 + 1):
      if not n % x:
         return False
   return True

if  __name__ == "__main__":
   import time
   start = time.time()
   print highest_prime_factor(1238162376372637826)
   print time.time() - start
```

The code above works (with a bit of delay) for "1238162376372637826" but
extending it to

> 10902610991329142436630551158108608965062811746392
>   57767545600484549911304430471090261099132914243663
>   05511581086089650628117463925776754560048454991130443047

makes python go crazy. Is there any way so that just like above, i can have it
calculated it in no time?

Comment: 512-bit number is 155 digits, which is simply a Python `long`.  No special code is required.  There's really not much to this.  Except, of course, the actual algorithm for factoring large primes.   Do you need the algorithm?  What do you have so far?

Comment: Um.  You are aware that factorizing a general 512-bit number is at the very limits of what can currently be done on a single machine in a reasonable amount of time? Here's a quote from wikipedia:

"As of the end of 2007, [...] general-form numbers of up to about 520 bits can be factored in a few months on a few PCs by a single person without any special mathematical experience."

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization_records

Comment: -1: "Is there any way so that just like above, i can have it calculated it in no time?"  Asking such a question indicates that you're really unclear on what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

For a Python-based solution, you might want to look at [pyecm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyecm/) On a system with gmpy installed also, pyecm found the following factors:

101, 521, 3121, 9901, 36479, 300623, 53397071018461, 1900381976777332243781

There still is a 98 digit unfactored composite:

60252507174568243758911151187828438446814447653986842279796823262165159406500174226172705680274911

Factoring this remaining composite using ECM may not be practical.

Edit: After a few hours, the remaining factors are

6060517860310398033985611921721

and

9941808367425935774306988776021629111399536914790551022447994642391

Answer (score 2):

This should be a better fit then the trivial approach for large numbers (although with this kind of number crunching every pure Python implementation will take a while): [Pollard Rho prime factorization](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577037-pollard-rho-prime-factorization/).

Comment: The Pollard tests generally don't handle that large of an input in practical time. Rho looks for relatively small factors. P-1 and P+1 algorithms look for primes who are one more or less than a number whose factors are all small. None are adequate for 512 bits today unless you have a special number.

Comment: @phkahler: thanks for commenting; did not know that. I've always found Pollard to be very fast for (relatively) large numbers, but off course I've never thrown 512 bits at it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install an extension, [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) would help -- see my answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019040/how-many-numbers-below-n-are-coprimes-to-n), specifically the `def prime_factors(x)` function in the code I show there.

In pure Python (without any extension allowed) it's a tad harder and a lot slower, see the code [here](http://blog.dhananjaynene.com/2009/01/2009-is-not-a-prime-number-a-python-program-to-compute-factors/) for example (but don't hold your breath while it runs on your huge numbers;-).

Answer (score -1):

```
('''==============================================================================='''
>        '''              CALCULATE  HIGHEST PRIME
> FACTOR                                  '''
>
> '''===============================================================================''')
>
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> def highest_prime_factor(n):
>    if isprime(n):
>       return n
>    for x in xrange(2,n ** 0.5 + 1):
>       if not n % x:
>          return highest_prime_factor(n/x)
> def isprime(n):
>    for x in xrange(2,n ** 0.5 + 1):
>       if not n % x:
>          return False
>    return True
> if  __name__ == "__main__":
>    import time
>    start = time.time()
>    print highest_prime_factor(1238162376372637826)
>    print time.time() - start
```

the code works with a bit of delay on the number : "1238162376372637826" but
extending it to
(109026109913291424366305511581086089650628117463925776754560048454991130443047109026109913291424366305511581086089650628117463925776754560048454991130443047)
makes python go crazy. Is there any way just like above, i can have it
calculated it in no time.

Comment: You should have put this in your question (Stackoverflow does not follow the traditional forum flow but is question-answers based). I'll put it in for you, it would be best if you removed this 'answer' then...

Comment: If I had away to factor large primes in "no time", I would be a very rich man.