# Iterating over parts of the Stern-Brocot tree in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration

My goal is to iterate over the pairs [a,b] a coprime to b and a+b<=n. For example, if n=8, I want to iterate over [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [1, 3], [2, 5], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7].
My first thought was a recursive function using the Stern-Brocot tree:

```
def Stern_Brocot(n,a=0,b=1,c=1,d=1):
if(a+b+c+d>n):
    return 0
x=Stern_Brocot(n,a+c,b+d,c,d)
y=Stern_Brocot(n,a,b,a+c,b+d)
if(x==0):
    if(y==0):
        return [a+c,b+d]
    else:
        return [a+c]+[b+d]+y
else:
    if(y==0):
        return [a+c]+[b+d]+x
    else:
        return [a+c]+[b+d]+x+y
```

As expected,

```
>>> Stern_Brocot(8)
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7]
```

And for n<=995, it works well. But suddenly at n>=996, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    a=Stern_Brocot(996)
  File "C:\Users\Pim\Documents\C Programmeren en Numerieke Wisk\Python\PE\PE127.py", line 35, in Stern_Brocot
    y=Stern_Brocot(n,a,b,a+c,b+d)
...
  File "C:\Users\Pim\Documents\C Programmeren en Numerieke Wisk\Python\PE\PE127.py", line 35, in Stern_Brocot
    y=Stern_Brocot(n,a,b,a+c,b+d)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

And since I want n to equal 120000, this approach won't work.
So my question is: what would be a good approach to iterate over parts of the Stern_Brocot tree? (if there's another way to iterate over coprime integers, that'd be good as well).

Comment: possibly linked with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019040/how-many-numbers-below-n-are-coprimes-to-n

Comment: Not really: that was about calculating [totients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function), this question is about iterating over coprime integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an non-recursive implementation

```
def Stern_Brocot(n):
    states = [(0, 1, 1, 1)]
    result = []
    while len(states) != 0:
        a, b, c, d = states.pop()
        if a + b + c + d <= n:
            result.append((a+c, b+d))
            states.append((a, b, a+c, b+d))
            states.append((a+c, b+d, c, d))
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks! Since I wanted to do something with the values directly, I removed the code from the function, and changed `result.append((a+c,b+d))` to `do something with a+c and b+d`, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Before defining `Stern_Brocot`, add `sys.setrecursionlimit(120000)`. This will set the program's recursion limit to 120000.

So, instead, you can do this:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(120000)

def Stern_Brocot(n,a=0,b=1,c=1,d=1):
    if(a+b+c+d>n):
        return 0
    x=Stern_Brocot(n,a+c,b+d,c,d)
    y=Stern_Brocot(n,a,b,a+c,b+d)
    if(x==0):
        if(y==0):
            return [a+c,b+d]
        else:
            return [a+c]+[b+d]+y
    else:
        if(y==0):
            return [a+c]+[b+d]+x
        else:
            return [a+c]+[b+d]+x+y
```