# Created function doesn't work (Python)

Tags: python, math, modular-arithmetic, ceil

I'm fairly new to python, and I tried to use it to make a program to figure out the n-th term to the Stern-Brocot Sequence (you can look that up, and that is why my function is called SBSeq). For some reason, it will not work, and it comes up with errors, like this:

```
File "C:/Python27/Factorials.py", line 6, in SBSeq
return ((n%2)*SBSeq(ceil(n/2)-1))+SBSeq(ceil(n/2))
```

Which eventually goes to this:

```
File "C:/Python27/Factorials.py", line 5, in SBSeq
if n == 1: return 1
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

This is the original code.

```
import math
from math import ceil

def SBSeq(n):

if n == 1: return 1
return ((n%2)*SBSeq(ceil(n/2)-1))+SBSeq(ceil(n/2))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The OP of the following question has the same problem as you. Please, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997970/iterating-over-parts-of-the-stern-brocot-tree-in-python

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile. Please post some valid code.

Comment: I guess function is called with negative inputs, and for negative inputs there is no early exit condition, `ceil(n/2)-1` looks suspicious. Note that `0*some_function()` won't short-circuit to 0.

Comment: @Borja I did check that, and it does not have the same problem as mine. I am generating a specific term in the sequence, while he/she is generating a list.

Comment: @juanchopanza It does compile (well, in Python 2.7.9, anyway). I didn't put the version in... sorry.

Comment: There's no way that compiles. http://ideone.com/mVjYPv

Comment: @juanchopanza Um... can't you just copy and paste the code into Python IDLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the indentation issue is not a real issue, the issue is that your numbers can reach below `1` when going recursively, and then once it reaches below `1` (that is n reaches `0` ) , it keeps on calling SBSeq recursively without exiting.

The condition in the start of recursive function should be `if n <= 1 : return 1`.

Code -

```
def SBSeq(n):
    if n <= 1: return 1
    return ((n%2)*SBSeq(ceil(n/2)-1))+SBSeq(ceil(n/2))
```

Answer (score 1):

`SBSeq(2)` calls `SBSeq(0)`, `SBSeq(0)` calls `SBSeq(-1)`, and `SBSeq(-1)` calls `SBSeq(-1)` forever.

Just add a special case for `SBSeq(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

From the debugger, you can find that `SBSeq(2)` calls `SBSeq(0)`, and then infinitely calls `SBSeq(-1)`. The function also has to terminate when `n` get lower than or equal to 1.

This is the improved function:

```
import math
from math import ceil

def SBSeq(n):
    if n <= 1: return 1 # not n == 1
    return ((n%2)*SBSeq(ceil(n/2)-1))+SBSeq(ceil(n/2))
```