# An Explanation for the totient finder in this program

Tags: python, math

I need an explanation for the program suggested in the edit in the first answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019040/how-many-numbers-below-n-are-coprimes-to-n). It is a program to find the totients of a range of numbers. Can somebody provide a simple explanation? (Ignore the summation part for now, I need to find out how the **init** method finds the totients.) I know there is an explanation in the answer, but that is an explanation for different programs, I need an explanation for this particular one.

```
class Totient:
def __init__(self, n):
    self.totients = [1 for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(2, n):
        if self.totients[i] == 1:
            for j in range(i, n, i):
                self.totients[j] *= i - 1
                k = j / i
                while k % i == 0:
                    self.totients[j] *= i
                    k /= i
def __call__(self, i):
    return self.totients[i]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from itertools import imap
    totient = Totient(10000)
    print sum(imap(totient, range(10000)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variant of the Sieve of Eratosthenes for finding prime numbers.

If you want to know the totient of a single number *n*, the best way to find it is to factor *n* and take the product of 1 less than each factor; for instance, 30 = 2 * 3 * 5, and subtracting 1 from each factor, then multiplying, gives the totient 1 * 2 * 4 = 8. But if you want to find the totients of all the numbers less than a given *n*, a better approach than factoring each of them is sieving. The idea is simple: Set up an array *X* from 0 to *n*, store *i* in each *X<sub>i</sub>*, then run through the array starting from 0 and whenever *X<sub>i</sub>* = *i* loop over the multiples of *i*, multiplying each by *i* − 1.

Further discussion and code at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/07/10/sieving-for-totients/).

Comment: I see your explanation, but can you make it clearer by citing important lines in the program and what they do? That would be more helpful, as it all is still a bit hazy to me. It would be helpful if you can trace out a particular totient for me.. though i understand the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: Do it yourself. By hand. Sieve the totients less than 25. That should show you what is happening.

Comment: Wait a min, if you have some factors repeating while factorisation for eg, in the case of 20: THe factorisation is 2*2*5. Thus do you subtract from both of the twos or only one of them, i.e, is the totient 1*1*4, or 1*2*4?

Comment: I think you subtract from only one of the similar factors, right?

Comment: Yup its only one of them, i misunderstood your previous statement, and thus wasn't getting it........

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what the code is doing -- but frankly it looks pretty bad. It clearly is trying to use that Euler's totient function is multiplicative, meaning that a,b are relatively prime then t(a,b) = t(a)*t(b), together with the fact that if p is a prime then t(p) = p-1. But -- it seems to be using crude trial division to determine such things. If you really want to calculate the totient of all numbers in a given range then you should use an algorithm that sieves the numbers as you go along.

Here is a version which sieves as it goes and exploits the multiplicative nature to the hilt. At each pass through the main loop it starts with a prime, p which hasn't yet been processed. It determines all powers of p <= n and then uses a direct formula for these powers (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function ). Once these totients have been added, it forms all possible products <= n of these powers and the numbers for which the totients have been previously computed. This gives a whole slew of numbers to add to the list of previously determined numbers. At most sqrt(n) passes need to be made through the main loop. It runs almost instantly for n = 10000. It returns a list where the ith value is the totient of i (with t(0) = 0 for convenience):

```
def allTotients(n):

    totients = [None]*(n+1) #totients[i] will contain the t(i)
    totients[0] = 0 
    totients[1] = 1

    knownTotients = [] #known in range 2 to n
    p = 2
    while len(knownTotients) < n - 1:
        powers = [p]
        k = 2
        while p ** k <= n:
            powers.append(p ** k)
            k +=1
        totients[p] = p - 1

        for i in range(1,len(powers)):
            totients[powers[i]] = powers[i] - powers[i-1]

        #at this stage powers represent newly discovered totients
        #combine with previously discovered totients to get still more
        newTotients = powers[:]
        for m in knownTotients:
            for pk in powers:
                if m*pk > n: break
                totients[m*pk] = totients[m]*totients[pk]
                newTotients.append(m*pk)
        knownTotients.extend(newTotients)

        #if there are any unkown totients -- the smallest such will be prime

        if len(knownTotients) < n-1:
            p = totients.index(None)
    return totients
```

For completeness sake, here is a Python implementation of the algorithm to compute the totient of a single number which user448810 described in their answer:

```
from math import sqrt

#crude factoring algorithm: 

small_primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,
                53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]

def factor(n):
    #returns a list of prime factors
    factors = []
    num = n
    #first pull out small prime factors
    for p in small_primes:
        while num % p == 0:
            factors.append(p)
            num = num // p
        if num == 1: return factors
    #now do trial division, starting at 101
    k = 101
    while k <= sqrt(num):
        while num % k == 0:
            factors.append(k)
            num = num // k
        k += 2
    if num == 1:
        return factors
    else:
        factors.append(num)
        return factors

def totient(n):
    factors = factor(n)
    unique_factors = set()
    t = 1
    for p in factors:
        if p in unique_factors:
            t *= p
        else:
            unique_factors.add(p)
            t *= (p-1)
    return t
```